# insert Empty Textbox value in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have some textbox which can have empty value. When I am trying to insert that textbox.text in insert command then it show error in sql. I want the automatic check when textbox is empty it will insert null in database in sql server 2008 R2. I am using normal insert into command and I do not want to use procedure(too clumsy). 
please help me anyone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the table structure and what is the datatype and make it nullable field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure about your code, but it should be like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into yourTable(ID, Col1, Col2) VALUES (@ID, @Col1, @Col2);";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", yourID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) ? 
                                          DBNull.Value: textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text) ?
                                          DBNull.Value : textBox2.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can check for Empty String using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, pass null accordingly. Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, if you want to consider spaces as valid values.

Comment: A string consisting of blank characters (say, a single space) if not empty, but you're treating it as empty. I cannot tell whether that's what the OP wants, but it's not what the OP asks for, that's simply `string.IsNullOfEmpty`.

Comment: @hvd, I can only guess that the OP would consider whitespaces as empty, but you are right I should add that in my answer.

Comment: Yes, inserting `null` pre-edit was not the right call - `DBNull.Value` being the key.  Otherwise very clear, explanatory code from the start.

Comment: @J0e3gan, yes, using ORM frameworks, I got use to `null` rather than `DBNull.Value` :)

Comment: Fair enough.  We're roughin' it in this case. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using direct insert query

```
"insert into table_name (column1,column2,column3) values("+column1value+","+column2value+","+textbox.Text.Trim()!=""?textbox.Text.Trim():DBNull.Value+")";
```

Even if you are using parameterised query, you can use the same expression

```
textbox.Text.Trim()!=""?textbox.Text.Trim():DBNull.Value
```

Comment: This example is a candidate for SQL injection. I would always recommend using parameters and not directly building sql statements by injecting text that's provided by users. At minimum, you should ensure that you are escaping SQL characters.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. parameterised query is always better. Dont use direct queries, will lead to sql injection. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnecction(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    string qry = "INSERT TargetTable (TargetColumn) VALUES (@TextValue)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TextValue", String.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text) ? DBNull.Value : textBox.Text));
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sex)
        {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}
```